# How often do the contents of a CPU register change?

Tags: cpu, hardware, cpu-registers, low-level

Does the data that CPU registers hold change often? The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register) describes the registers as "*a quickly accessible location...of a small amount of fast storage*". I'm assuming the memory is fast because a register is accessed and modified often?

Comment: Yes, register files are usually multi-ported SRAM so they can be read and written multiple times per clock cycle.  For example, a loop with 4 `add reg,reg` instructions and a `jnz` can run at 1 iteration per clock on Intel Skylake, reading 8 registers and writing 4 per clock (not counting FLAGS as separate, although it's also written 4 times)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, data registers may change on subsequent instructions which is quite often. There are more complications with superscalarity, out-of-order execution, pipelining, register renaming, etc which complicate the analysis, but even on a simple in-order CPU, a register can change as often as once per instruction. A plausible program may have a run of many instructions, all affecting the same register:

```
// Type your code here, or load an example.
int polynom(int num) {
    return num * num + 2 * num + 1;
}
```

which compiles as:

```
polynom(int):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
      * mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
      * imul    eax, eax
      * mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        add     edx, edx
      * add     eax, edx
      * add     eax, 1
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Note the many writes to the `eax` register, noted with an asterisk. In this little function, five almost-consecutive instructions write to this specific register, meaning that we can expect the *program-visible state of `eax`*<sup>1</sup> to change at a rate of over 1 GHz if this code were to be called in a tight loop.

On a more fundamental note, there are some architectural registers that *almost always* change on every instruction. The most evident of these is the program counter (called PC in many contexts, `EIP` on x86, `RIP` on x86_64). Because this register points to the currently executing instruction, it must certainly change with every instruction, barring counterexamples like x86 REP encodings or an instruction that simply jumps to itself.

<sup>1</sup> Again, barring architectural considerations like register renaming, which uses multiple physical registers to implement a single logical, program-visible register.

Answer (score 1):

Since modern CPU's run in GHz, CPU registers can change what they are storing hundred of millions or even billions of times per second.

Since most modern CPU's have ~128 registers, they would typically change values a few million times per second when performing many operations.

Comment: You're talking about the physical registers that architectural registers are renamed onto, I think, and you mean how quickly any individual one changes.  That's an important distinction.  And you're assuming that register renaming round robins onto the physical registers, rather than using the lowest free register number, for example.

Comment: Your math seems low; assuming Skylake that's up to 4 register writes per clock * 4 GHz = 16 reg writes per nanosecond, or up to 89 changes per physical register per microsecond on average, assuming renaming onto just its 180 physical integer registers, ignoring vector/FP (another 168-entry PRF).  https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/skylake_(client)#Renaming_.26_Allocation Fun fact: `vzeroupper` can logically modify 16 registers per clock cycle, 4x more than the usual 4.  Even assuming a more realistic IPC, and some uops not writing regs, still maybe 20 MHz avg per phys reg.